# How to change property of element removed from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, this

`this.statues.shift();` is isolating the correct element and removing it from the array. When this happens though, person.stoned needs to be false. Any pointers? Thank you.

**Code:**

```
class Medusa {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.statues = [];
  }

  stare(person) {
    person.stoned = true;

    this.statues.push(person);

    if(this.statues.length > 3) {
      this.statues.shift();
    }
  }
};

class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.stoned = false;
  }
};
```

Comment: this.statues.shift() remove the first array element. if you need set false for first element?
if(this.statues.length > 3) {
this.statues[0].stoned=false;
this.statues.shift();
}

or 

if(this.statues.length > 3) {
this.statues[0].stoned=false;
this.statues.splice(0,1);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since objects are passed by reference, you could do that inline, using the return value of shift

```
    if(this.statues.length > 3) {
          (this.statues.shift()).stoned = false
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I need to work on that dot notation more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save shifted object and set its property, like that:

```
if(this.statues.length > 3) {
  const unstoned = this.statues.shift();
  unstoned.stoned = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(this.statues.length > 3) { this.statues[0].stoned=false; this.statues.shift(); }
```

or

```
if(this.statues.length > 3) { this.statues[0].stoned=false; this.statues.splice(0,1); }
```

Comment: Thank you for this!